# Inconsistent results from Wolfram Cloud

Tags: linear-algebra

More specifically, I was using the ["no sign-in" option of Wolfram Programming Lab](https://www.wolfram.com/programming-lab/).

I was trying to solve a matrix problem, with the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
m={{2,0},{0,1}}*2500;
k={{3,-1},{-1,1}}*20000 Pi^2;
w1=N[2Pi,5];
w2=6.2832;
D1=Det[k-w1^2*m]
D2=Det[k-w2^2*m]
```

Since the numerical values of w1 and w2 should be close, I expect the numerical values of D1 and D2 should also be close. Strangely, Wolfram Cloud gives very different values:

[image]

It took me a whole night to pin down this segment of code. I don't know if this is only due to my computer/browser, or some one else, if runs the same code, will have same problem? What happened?

---

**Edit**

Suppose I would like to compare the determinant using exact symbolic $2\pi$ and function `N[2Pi,5]`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
m={{2,0},{0,1}}*2500;
k={{3,-1},{-1,1}}*20000 Pi^2;
w1=N[2Pi,5];
w2=2Pi;
D1=Det[k-w1^2*m]
D2=Det[k-w2^2*m]
```

The result is not exactly the same:
[image]

So, is `N[2Pi,5]` exactly equal to $2\pi$ or not? What does the function `N` actually do?

Comment: Suppose small epsilon then `ClearAll["Global\`*"]; m={{2,0},{0,1}}*2500; k={{3,-1},{-1,1}}*20000 Pi^2; w1=2Pi+epsilon; FullSimplify[Det[k-w1^2*m]]` returns `12500000*epsilon*(epsilon - 2*Pi)*(epsilon + 4*Pi)*(epsilon + 6*Pi)` and for small epsilon that is approximately 12500000*epsilon*-2*Pi*4*Pi*6*Pi== -600000000*epsilon*Pi^3` so any small error in w is multiplied by about 1.86*10^10 in the determinant.

Comment: No, `N[x, p]`, represents, if possible, the value of `x` approximated to a precision of `p` digits.  Read the documentation on `N`.

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumbersOverview.html, esp. the tutorials about exact, approximate and arbitrary-precision numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I get the same result in Mathematica, so it's not a Mathematica Online issue.  I don't think it's even a Mathematica issue.  It's due to two factors:

1. `w1` is not equal to `w2`, because `N` doesn't actually truncate `2 Pi` to five digits
2. `Det[k-w^2*m]` changes quickly, so any little inaccuracy in `w` becomes a big discrepancy in `Det[k-w^2*m]`

To see #1:

```
w1 == 2 \[Pi]
(* True *)
w1 - w2
(* -0.0000146928 *)
```

To see #2:

```
Plot[Det[k - w^2*m], {w, 6.2831, 6.2833}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Regarding #1, it appears that the determinants calculated using $2\pi$ and `N[2Pi,5]` are not exactly the same. I have edited the question.

Comment: Agreed, this is about numeric math and not Mathematica per se (as this response also notes).